# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when trying to retrieve json data

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to get the data from the following url https://www.gov.uk/api/foreign-travel-advice.json

I have used http://json2csharp.com/ to extract the classes, but I just cannot get the data i'm after.

Can anyone who has more experience than me please take a look and let me know where i'm going wrong.

This is the code throwing the null referance

```
var data = (from j in o["countries"].Children()
                        select new Country
                        {
                                Id      = (string)j["id"],
                                WebUrl  = (string)j["name"]
                        });
```

Full Code

```
namespace Web.Domain.FCO.Countries
{
    public class Details
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public object ShortDescription { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class ContentWithTag
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string WebUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class Details2
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public object ShortDescription { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class ContentWithTag2
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string WebUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class Parent
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public object WebUrl { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Details2 Details { get; set; }
        public ContentWithTag2 ContentWithTag { get; set; }
        public object parent { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tag
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public object WebUrl { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Details Details { get; set; }
        public ContentWithTag ContentWithTag { get; set; }
        public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    }

    public class Related
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string WebUrl { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Format { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public string Group { get; set; }
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Identifier { get; set; }
        public string WebUrl { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public string ChangeDescription { get; set; }
        public List<object> Synonyms { get; set; }
    }

    public class Details3
    {
        public string NeedId { get; set; }
        public bool BusinessProposition { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
        public bool NeedExtendedFont { get; set; }
        public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    }

    public class ResponseInfo
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class FcoFullDetails
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string WebUrl { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Format { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
        public List<Related> Related { get; set; }
        public Details3 Details { get; set; }
        public List<object> RelatedExternalLinks { get; set; }
        public ResponseInfo ResponseInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class IdAndUrl
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string WebUrl { get; set; } 
    }

    public class DisplayFcoCountryList : IDisplayFcoCountryList
    {
        public IEnumerable<Country> ListOfCountries()
        {
            var doc = FcoCountriesAdvice.GetFcoCountryLinks().Result;
           // var jd = new [] {JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(doc)};
            var jd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(doc);
            JObject o = JObject.Parse(jd.ToString());

            //var data = (from j in o["countries"]
                        var data = (from j in o["countries"].Children()
                        select new Country
                        {
                                Id      = (string)j["id"],
                                WebUrl  = (string)j["name"]
                        });
            return data;
        }
    }
    public static class FcoCountriesAdvice
    {
        private static readonly string Key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FCO_AdviceURL"];

        public static async Task<string> GetFcoCountryLinks()
        {
            using (var ta = new HttpClient())
            {
                const string cacheDataTravelAdvice = "FCOCountryLinks";

                ObjectCache travelCache = MemoryCache.Default;
                var objectInCache = travelCache.Get(cacheDataTravelAdvice) as string;

                if (objectInCache != null)
                {
                    return objectInCache;
                }

                var url = await ta.GetStringAsync(string.Format("{0}", Key)).ConfigureAwait(false);

                var policy = new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15) };

                travelCache.Add(cacheDataTravelAdvice, url, policy);

                return url;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should probably use details/countries, see here http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and paste inside the json, you can see the structure

Comment: Hi Alessio, thanks for the link, I was looking at wrong structure, should have been  var data = (from j in o["details"]["countries"].Children() your link help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A nullref exception while creating a linq statement will most likely mean that the part: `o["countries"].Children()` returned NULL thus can not be iterated over. Try what happens if you debug it with some easy statements:

> Console.WriteLine(o["countries"]);
>
> Console.WriteLine(o["countries"].Children());
>
> Console.WriteLine(o["countries"].Children().Count());

Answer (score 0):

Try using a json deserializer like [JSON.net](http://json.codeplex.com/). This does all the json-c# conversion for you:

```
    //make request using the HttpClient class
    var client = new HttpClient{BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.gov.uk/api/")};
    var response = client.GetAsync("foreign-travel-advice.json").Result;

    //use Json.Net to convert json to c# classes using generics
    var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>    (response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alessio answer fixed the problem, after visiting the link he supplied, I noticed that i should have been using var data = (from j in o["details"]["countries"].Children() not var data = (from j in o["countries"].Children(). Problem is now fixed.